# How to pass parameter values to the custom NSLOG

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm developing one logger class for my application.NSLog will be printed only in debug mode. I have customized the NSLog where Name of the source file,Source code line number,Name of the class and method where NSLog() was called is printed.
That is , my current NSLOG looks like 
             (ClassName MethodName) (SourceFileName:LineNumber) NSLog output

Now, I want to log, parameter values of the methodname. How to get those parameter values in NSLog??? 
I want the output as 
         (ClassName MethodName) (SourceFileName:LineNumber) (Parameter Values) NSLog output

Answer (score 3):

Something like this should work

```
#define InstanceLog(fmt, ...) NSLog(@"(%@.%@)(%s:%d) " fmt, NSStringFromClass(self.class), NSStringFromSelector(_cmd), __FILE__, __LINE__, ##__VA_ARGS__)
```

You may use it as `NSLog` within Objective-C methods

```
InstanceLog(@"simple string");
InstanceLog(@"%@ %@", @"hello", @"world");
```

Comment: That won't work;  fmt will be inserted into the resulting string without actually being formatted with VA_ARGS.  You'll need an extra [NSString stringWIthFormat:] in there.

Comment: @bbum thanks. got wrong macro token: it should be `##`, not `#` before `__VA_ARGS__`

Comment: That won't work, either.  You have to evaluate fmt + __VA_ARGS__ separately.

Comment: I wrote and used dozens of macros like this, they work just like they should. Either you know some corner case in which this one breaks or you didn't actually try to substitute it.

Comment: I'm surprised that particular C-ism works so flawlessly with Objective-C.   It certainly didn't the last time I tried it, but that was probably more than a decade ago.   Thanks!

Comment: Maybe that time some flags prevented preprocessor from substituting varargs correctly, but I don't know much about gcc behavior history, so it's a blind guess.

Answer (score 2):

There isn't a way to automatically introspect the values passed to a method.  Even in DEBUG builds (where the optimizer is out of the way), any attempts to write code to introspect said iVars is going to be incredibly complex (you'll have to dive into the symbol tables, extract offsets, etc, and then try and find the arguments that were likely destroyed in the attempt to grab them).

So, no, no way to really automate that.

In general, though, any such logging mechanism would generate such an atrociously huge amount of output that you are far better off creating (potentially debugging only) logging that is both configurable and highly tuned to your application.

---

You can pass args like this (thanks to @hoha for the simpler version).

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

#define FooLog(fmt, ...) NSLog(@"(%s): %@", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, ## __VA_ARGS__)

@interface Bob:NSObject
@end
@implementation Bob
- (void)yourUncle
{
    FooLog(@"%@", self);
}
@end

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        NSString *w = @"World";
        FooLog(@"Hello, %@!", w);
        [[Bob new] yourUncle];
    }
}
```

Output:

```
2013-09-02 10:51:49.447 Untitled[60967:507] (int main(int, char **)): Hello, World!
2013-09-02 10:51:49.453 Untitled[60967:507] (-[Bob yourUncle]): <Bob: 0x7fde8840a490>
```

Answer (score 0):

for handle custom logging you can use or refer following link.

You can customise Lumberjack as per you needs.

[Lumberjack error logging for ios](https://github.com/bdurand/lumberjack/)

[Lumberjack error logging tutorial](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/cocoalumberjack-logging-on-steroids/)

Comment: Lumberjack logging framework is third party framework right??? I dont want to use any third party framework

Comment: Yes, but Lumberjack is open source library for logging and you can use codes from this in you own programs.<br> otherwise you can follow this link for custom logging [link here](http://weakreference.wordpress.com/2011/06/22/overriding-nslog-on-ios/)

Comment: Thanks.. I don't know whether open source library is accepted in my application. I have created has specified in that link but I want to log my parameter values as I mentioned earlier in my question.